# Hug sides of screen with autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I have a form style layout in which I'd like the labels to hug the left side of the screen, and the fields to hug the right side of the screen. The labels should remain at a fixed size, and there should be a fixed margin between field and label, so that the fields increase in width as the screen increases in width.

I'd like it to look like the left (iPhone SE, left) below on all screen sizes. However, when I resize to a larger width (iPhone 7, right), the fields on the right don't increase their width to hug the right side of the screen, despite their trailing space constraint:

[image: correct]
[image: incorrect]

And, all of this is in a scroll view, although I don't think that should matter, since it's just a container.

My full list of constraints are:

[image]

Any ideas what constraints I should change/add to have the subviews behave like I want them to?

Comment: You need to constrain the trailing edge of your fields to the trailing edge of the scroll view

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe they are constrained that way. One of my constraints is `trailing = Amount Field.trailing + 15`, and then all of the other fields's trailing edges are aligned to this edge and each other. However, none of the fields actually stay 15px away from the right edge when rendering.

Comment: Right, I was looking for that but I couldn't see it.  Are you getting warnings about unsatisfiable constraints?  Have you constrained the width of the receipt scrollview in some way?  Rather than constraining the trailing edges of all of the fields to each other, just constrain them to the trailing edge of the container as you have done with the Amount Field. This may help show where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Constraint the trailing edges of all labels. Constraint `$0.00` label trailing edges with superview. Align trailing edges of `Description` , `Today` , `View/Edit` labels with `$0.00`. [image]

Make sure to  set no of lines to 0 and text alignment to right.

[image]

Comment: I believe they already are constrained as your described, but it's not working. If you look about halfway down the image I posted of my constraints, you can see `trailing = Amount Field.trailing + 15` but this constraint isn't actually followed when rendering. And, all of the trailing edges of the fields are aligned with each other.

Comment: The number of lines isn't a property that's available on text fields, and I'd like the text fields to be right aligned

Comment: hav you set text alignment to Left for all labels

Comment: I just tried setting the alignment to left, just to check if that changed anything, but it doesn't appear it does :/

Comment: trailing = Amount Field.trailing + 15  AmountField is constrained with superview??

Comment: try removing AnountField.leading = Amount.Trailing +15  Description Field.leading = Description.Trailing

Comment: and constraint fields to fixed width

Comment: you are adding leading as well as trailing constraints to all text field. Just add trailing constraint to Amount field and fixed width , thenceforth align trailing edges of Today , View/Edit labels with Amount Field.